# как найти координаты точки симметричной другой точке относительно прямой?

Tags: android, геометрия, path

Требуется найти координаты точки , которая симметрична данной точке относительно линии определённой в объекте Path

Comment: Меня гложет подозрение, что определение "линии" у Вас в голове отличается от традиционного.

Comment: "точки лежат так, что линии нет?" ето как?) если "невозможно сделать в коде", то зачем спрашивать здесь?) если есть 2 точки - есть линия

Comment: Имеется в виду разница между понятием "отрезок" (линия) и "прямая" , то есть прямая между точками в любом случае лежит , но "видимый" отрезок лежащий на прямой может и не находится между точками,

Answer (score 2):

Сам сформулирую:
Линия задана точками `A` и `B`
Дана точка `P`, требуется найти симметричную ей относительно прямой `AB`

Найдём векторы

```
AP = P - A
AB = B - A
```

Проекция `P` на прямую даёт точку `N` такую, что `PN`  перпендикулярно `AB`, соответственно их скалярное произведение равно нулю. Вектор `AN` коллинеарен (сонаправлен) `AB` и может быть выражен как последний, умноженный на скалярный коэффициент `t`, причём коэффициент может лежать за пределами интервала `0..1` (при этом проекция находится вне отрезка `AB`):

```
PN = AN - AP = t * AB - AP
AB * (t * AB - AP) = 0
t * Dot(AB, AB) = Dot(AB, AP)
t = Dot(AB, AP) / Dot(AB, AB)
AN = AB * t
```

и в результате

```
AN = AB * Dot(AP, AB) / Dot(AB, AB)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вектор разности

```
PN = AB * Dot(AP, AB) / Dot(AB, AB) - AP
```

Симметричная точка

```
S = P + 2 * PN  = 
    P + 2 * AB * Dot(AP, AB) / Dot(AB, AB) - 2 * AP
```

Данный подход позволяет найти проекцию и симметричную точку без нормализации векторов.

Comment: Вопрос не в том , как такая задача решается в геометрии , а в том как реализовать это решение в коде - синтаксис кода не позволяет использовать уравнения типа: AB * (t * AB - AP) = 0 , а значит и производить преобразования уравнений и решать их - в коде могут быть только выражения , возвращающие конкретное значение (число) - вот такое выражение мне и нужно

Comment: Хм... Реализация формул в коде - один из важных навыков программиста.Например, при обучении заставляют квадратные уравнения решать, "синтаксис кода" при этом не мешает.  Готовые формулы в ответе содержатся.