# Вычислить координаты ортогональной проекции точки на отрезок

Tags: javascript, математика, геометрия

Проект для создания чертежей в `svg`, на нативном `js`.

Столкнулся со следующей задачей:

Известны координаты ***3х*** точек `A B C` на плоскости. Точки `A B` являются началом и концом отрезка `AB`. Нужно найти координаты ортогональной проекции `(точка D)` точки `С` на отрезок `АВ`. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Проекцию можно найти, используя скалярное произведение векторов

```
 D = A + AB * Dot(AC, AB) / Dot(AB, AB)
```

В псевдокоде:

```
 abx = B.X - A.X
 aby = B.Y - A.Y
 dacab = (C.X - A.X) * abx + (C.Y - A.Y) * aby
 dab = abx * abx + aby * aby
 t = dacab / dab
 D.X = A.X + abx * t
 D.Y = A.Y + aby * t
```

[Здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/915498/291659) немного другие обозначения (C=P, N=D) и пояснения

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Посмотрел Ваше решение - кажется, то, что нужно. Спасибо. Что такое скалярный коэффициент? В гугле, по запросу "скалярный коэффициент", ничего внятного не нашел.

Comment: Не скалярный коэффициент, а скалярное произведение векторов (в школе его изучают). Сумма покомпонентных произведений `Dot(V,U) = V.X*U.X + V.Y*U.Y`

Answer (score 0):

- Метод "пересечения":

  Если построить точку `С' = (Cx - (By - Ay), Cy + (Bx - Ax))`, то прямая `CC'` будет перпендикулярна прямой `AB`. Пересечение прямых `AB` и `CC'` даст вам точку `D`.

  Метод "тяжеловат" с вычислительной точки зрения из-за того, что использует пересечение двух прямых в качестве примитива. Но прост в реализации, если такой примитив уже есть под руками.
- Метод "расстояния":

  Если `AA`, `BB` и `CC` - коэффициенты уравнения прямой, содержащей отрезок `AB` (легко вычисляются через координаты точек `A` и `B`), то величина

  ```
  DD = AA * Cx + BB * Cy + CC
  ```

  даст вам знаковое расстояние от этой прямой до точки `C`, домноженное на `|(AA, BB)|`. Если к точке `C` прибавить вектор `DD * (-AA, -BB)`, то мы получим точку, которая смещена относительно `C` в правильном направлении, но, условно выражаясь, "слишком далеко": расстояние превышает требуемое в `|(AA, BB)|^2` раз. Достаточно разделить смещение на эту величину - мы получим требуемую точку `D`

  ```
               DD 
  D = C + ------------ * (-AA, -BB)
          |(AA, BB)|^2
  ```

  Этот метод тоже несколько громоздок из-за "лишних" вычислений уравнения прямой, но может быть полезен, если вы и так уже знаете/вычисляете уравнение прямой, а также если вам в дополнение к точке проекции нужно еще вычислять и расстояние от `C` до `AB`.
- Метод "скалярного произведения":

  Очевидно, что

  ```
          |(A, D)|
  D = A + -------- * (A, B)
          |(A, B)|
  ```

  При этом скалярное произведение вектора `(A, C)` на вектор `(A, B)` - это длина проекции `(A, D)`, домноженная на `|(A, B)|`.

  ```
  (A, C)•(A, B) = |(A, D)| * |(A, B)|
  ```

  Тогда

  ```
          (A, C)•(A, B)
  D = A + ------------- * (A, B)
            |(A, B)|^2
  ```

(Можно показать, что если собрать все вычисления второго метода в одну формулу, то она "сократится" до третьего метода.)