# Как правильно посчитать координаты точки?

Tags: математика, canvas, геометрия

С математикой плохо дружу с детства, а тут пришлось на канве рисовать, возникли сложности.

У меня есть некая прямая, область выделения прямой шире чем она есть, сделано для touch удобства. Когда я делаю touch на прямую у меня должна появляться вершина (точка) и мне надо поставить эту точку на прямую вне зависимости что я тачнул немного левее. Картина для наглядности ниже:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите решение и если можно по пунктам, чтобы я уловил суть ибо говорю что с математикой увы туго, буду крайне 
благодарен.

Из исходных данных получается

> `A(x1,y1);`
>
> `B(x2,y2)` - прямая,
>
> `C(x3,y3)`
>
> На выходе должны быть откорректированные `C(x3, y3)`

Comment: "Откорректированные" каким образом? Тут приходит на ум ортогональная проекция: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/933182/%D0%92%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BA

Comment: Я ставлю эту точку C (она лежит не на линии), мне надо отредактировать ее координаты чтобы она пересеклась с линией

Comment: "Отредактировать ее координаты" - неясно поставленная задача. Это можно сделать сотней разных способов. Какой вам нужен? Я дал вам ссылку на один из вариантов.

Comment: Найти точку, перпендикуляр к прямой(в гугле есть), найти расстония между точкой пересечения перпендикуляра и отрезка(в гугле тоже есть), если расстояние меньше некого числа, то принять точку касания за точку пересечения перпендикуляра и отрезка

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам уже в комментариях посоветовали кое-что, вот сделал реализацию на javascript

```js
let p0 = [100, 66];
let p1 = [500, 99];

d3.select("path").attr("d", "M" + p0 + "L" + p1);

d3.select("svg").on("mousemove", function() { 

  let p2 = d3.mouse(this);
  
  let x1 = p1[0] - p0[0]; 
  let y1 = p1[1] - p0[1];
  let x2 = p2[0] - p0[0]; 
  let y2 = p2[1] - p0[1];
  
  let t = (x2 * x1 + y2 * y1) / (x1 * x1 + y1 * y1);
        
  t = Math.min(1, Math.max(t, 0)); 
  
  d3.select('circle')
    .attr("cx", p0[0] + t * x1)
    .attr("cy", p0[1] + t * y1)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="600" height="175">
  <path stroke="green"></path>
  <circle fill="rgba(255,0,0,0.5)" r="5"></circle>
</svg>
```

Вот неплохая статья:

http://www.sunshine2k.de/coding/java/PointOnLine/PointOnLine.html

Вот результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Thank you, your example is perfect!

Comment: @Praud рад что помог, обращайтесь