# Перпендикуляр от точки к отрезку на плоскости

Tags: математика, векторы

Все точки заданы координатами. При построении перпендикуляра от точки к отрезку хочу узнать, попадает ли он(перпендикуляр) на заданный отрезок или нет. Мой вариант таков: посчитать угол ∠МАВ и ∠МВА. От точки можно построить перпендикуляр при условии,что угол будет и в первом и во втором случае 0°< ∠ < 90°.[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UWoxB.jpg]

Comment: Проще - что нет тупого угла... :)

Comment: Так а саму проекцию найти нужно? Или нужно только ответить на вопрос "попадает/не попадает"?

Comment: @AnT только узнать о "попадании/не попадании".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Один из способов - посчитать скалярные произведения векторов `AB.dot.BM` и `AB.dot.AM`. Если знаки этих произведений разные, то проекция точки лежит на отрезке. (По сути - это сравнение углов с прямым без непосредственного их вычисления)

Если же сама проекция всё равно будет считаться, то можно, как [здесь сделано](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/933182/%D0%92%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BA/933188#933188), посмотреть величину `t` (отношение двух скалярных произведений `(AM.dot.AB) / (AB.dot.AB)`) - если она в пределах 0..1, то точка проекции лежит на отрезке.

Answer (score 4):

Вот нашел еще одно решение через библиотеку NumPy.

```
import numpy as np
vert = np.array([[-10, -10], [3, 3]])
point = np.array([-5, -5])

side1 = vert[1] - vert[0]
print("side coord", side1)
proj_side1 = point - vert[0]
if 0 <= np.dot(side1, proj_side1) <= np.dot(side1, side1):
    print("in line")
else:
    print("not in line")
```

Comment: Это реализация второго указанного мной способа.