# Расстояние между бесконечной линией и точкой в 3D

Tags: геометрия

Вычислить расстояние между бесконечной линией и точкой в 3D. Что необходимо изменить, чтобы вычислить расстояние между конечным отрезком и точкой?

Comment: Если расстояние между точкой и бесконечной линией Вы знаете, как посчитать, то наверное знаете, как найти точку пересечения этой бесконечной линии и перпендикуляра к ней от точки. Дальше все просто. Если эта точка принадлежит отрезку - ответ найден, если нет - считаете расстояние от точки до ближнего конца отрезка по теореме Пифагора

Answer (score 2):

Проекцию точки на отрезок в 3D можно вычислить так же, [как в двумерном случае](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/933182/%D0%92%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BA/933188#933188), через скалярное произведение. Если параметр t получается меньше нуля, то нужно считать расстояние до первого конца, если больше единицы - то до второго конца, иначе до проекции.