# Как вычислить перпендикуляр к прямой?

Tags: java, математика, геометрия, вычислительная-геометрия

Известны две точки прямой, например, {100, 100} и {200, 200}, и есть точка, не лежащая на прямой, например {200, 100}. Как определить, в какой точке относительно прямой будет перпендикуляр, если провести линию? Желателен ответ в коде Java.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/933182/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

В общем виде - вот:

```
double x1 = 100, y1 = 100, x2 = 200, y2 = 200, x3 = 200, y3 = 100;

double x = (x1 * x1 * x3 - 2 * x1 * x2 * x3 + x2 * x2 * x3 + x2 *
            (y1 - y2) * (y1 - y3) - x1 * (y1 - y2) * (y2 - y3)) / ((x1 - x2) *
                    (x1 - x2) + (y1 - y2) * (y1 - y2));
double y = (x2 * x2 * y1 + x1 * x1 * y2 + x2 * x3 * (y2 - y1) - x1 *
            (x3 * (y2 - y1) + x2 * (y1 + y2)) + (y1 - y2) * (y1 - y2) * y3) / ((
                        x1 - x2) * (x1 - x2) + (y1 - y2) * (y1 - y2));
```

Такой ответ устраивает? Упростите уж сами, ладно?...

**Update**

Раз желание узнать *КАК* прозвучало... Все просто.

Ищем точку (x,y), которая лежит на прямой через точки (x1,y1) и (x2,y2), и прямая через точки (x,y) и (x3,y3) перпендикулярна прямой через точки (x1,y1) и (x2,y2).

Первое условие -

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ну, а второе - произведение наклонов должно давать -1 (Уравнение прямой - y = kx + b, и для перпендикулярных прямых k<sub>1</sub>*k<sub>2</sub> = -1):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А дальше просто решаем эту систему уравнений...

Comment: вроде да, все работает. спасибо большое :)

Comment: @DynoCris не хотите узнать, почему это работает? Просто скопировали и вставили? 

Comment: @dIm0n хотелось бы)

Comment: @DynoCris посмотрите уравнение прямой с угловым коэффициентом https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Прямая, с помощью него по двум точкам из системы уравнений выводите коэффициенты `k, b` первой прямой, а для второй прямой надо сначала найти `k` (учитывая его определение и то, что вторая прямая перпендикулярна первой), а дальше подставить оставшуюся 3 точку и найти второе `b`. Теперь у вас есть оба уравнения прямых и для нахождения точки пересечения сначала приравниваете `y`, потом подставляете в любое из уравнений найденный `x` и находите `y`

Answer (score 2):

Для начала нужно найти уравнение прямой, к которой требуется провести перпендикуляр:

[image: Уравнение прямой по двум точкам]

В вашем случае оно простое: `y = 1x + 0` (прямая `y = ax + b`)

Далее уравнение перпендикуляра к прямой через точку `M(x1; y1)` можно найти так:

[image: Уравнение перпендикуляра]

Упрощаем и получаем `y = -x + 300`

Решаем систему уравнений, чтобы найти точку пересечения прямых:

```
y = -x + 300
y = x
```

```
x = -x + 300
x = 150
y = 150
```