# Как получить новые координаты центра кружка, чтобы он не пересекал контур?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, vector

Разбираюсь с Opencv на Python и делаю небольшой проект. В окне Opencv создаются кружки, которые можно толкать с помощью движений рук. Большую часть кода уже сделал - считывание движений рук и получение их контуров и создание кружков (данные кружков хранятся в глобальном массиве). Но не могу понять как толкать кружки.

Во время записи видео идет обработка каждого кадра. У меня есть контуры рук и координаты и радиусы кружков. То есть нужно пройтись по каждому кружку, проверить, пересекается ли он с контуром. Если нет, то всё хорошо, если пересекается, то нужно отодвинуть кружок перпендикулярно контуру, чтобы он перестал пересекаться. А потом уже по новым данным кружков отрисовать их (это тоже готово).

Но пока не могу понять как именно можно отодвинуть кружок?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно посчитать наименьшее расстояния от центра окружности до контура - в простейшем случае перебрав отрезки, составляющие контур, и считая длину перпендикуляра D из центра к отрезку (добавление - а также расстояния до углов!). Если она меньше R, то сдвигаете центр на вектор, коллинеарный этому перпендикуляру, с длиной R-D.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот код, но он не учитывает случай, когда проекция центра не попадает на отрезок, а пересечение есть, поэтому нужно ещё расстояния до концов отрезка проверять

```
import math
def proj(x1, y1, x2, y2, xp, yp):
    x12 = x2 - x1
    y12 = y2 - y1
    dotp = x12 * (xp - x1) + y12 * (yp - y1)
    dot12 = x12 * x12 + y12 * y12
    coeff = dotp / dot12
    lx = x1 + x12 * coeff
    ly = y1 + y12 * coeff
    return lx, ly, coeff

x1,y1,x2,y2,cx,cy,R = 0, 0, 10, 0, 5, 5, 6
lx, ly, cf = proj(x1, y1, x2, y2, cx, cy)
if 0<=cf<=1:   #проекция находится в пределах отрезка
    dx, dy  = cx - lx, cy - ly
    dist = math.hypot(dx, dy)
    if dist < R:    #окружность пересекает отрезок
        xshift = dx * (R-dist) / dist
        yshift = dy * (R-dist) / dist
        print(xshift, yshift)

>>> 0.0 1.0
```

Если проекция центра вне отрезка, но расстояние до одного из концов меньше радиуса, то окружность пересекает отрезок один раз или включает его в себя полностью. В таком случае нужно выбрать стратегию отталкивания от угла - любо смещаем на тот же самый найденный вектор (это самое простое), либо выбираем минимум длины из векторов от двух соседних сторон, либо двигаем по внешней биссектрисе, либо ещё что.

Если кружки могут заходить больше, чем на радиус, придётся учитывать, какая сторона контура внешняя, и направление отрезков. Кроме того, для сложного (невыпуклого) контура при сдвиге могут появиться новые пересечения,в этом случае придётся строить что-то вроде внешнего скелета (биссектрисы внешних углов до их пересечения и т.д.).

Однако для динамической системы можно предпросчитывать моменты касания окружности и контура, и придавать в этот момент окружности импульс по радиусу касания

Comment: Не совсем понял как можно сдвинуть круг. У меня есть координата центра круга, его радиус и координата ближайшей точки до круга, которая лежит на контуре и которая точно находится в круге. Нужно найти вектор от центра круга до точки на контуре. Вычесть из каждой координаты точки радиус. И потом прибавить этот результат к  центру круга?

Comment: Рисунок добавил.

Comment: Спасибо. Понял, что чтобы найти v, нужно найти u. А чтобы найти u, нужно из вектора радиуса вычесть вектор из точки в центр. Но как можно найти вектор радиуса?

Comment: Понял, нужно получить вектор из точки в центр. Потом по формуле c = r / d можно получить координаты (c * x, c * y), которые показывают смещение для точки. И теперь из начального вектора из точки в центр вычесть (c * x, c * y)

Comment: Вот здесь есть, как найти точку на отрезке  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/933182/

Comment: Всё еще не могу понять как это можно использовать. Мой способ тоже не сработал. Нашел еще один. У меня есть координаты точки. Я взял вектор из неё в координаты центра круга. Нашел его угол в радианах. И построил новый вектор из точки длиной D с углом в радианах. Это работает, но только если значения в векторе из точки в центр круга положительные. Не знаете как можно сделать так, чтобы и с отрицательными работало?

Comment: Спасибо большое, разобрался