# Функция 'отражения' точки относительно прямой

Tags: графика, геометрия

На плоскости есть прямая, заданная двумя точками A и B и точка P. Требуется узнать координаты симметричной точки относительно прямой (то есть что то вроде отражения этой точки по другую сторону прямой). Точки заданы декартовыми координатами. Подскажите функцию, желательно с объяснением. Все что находил по этой теме либо не работает на примерах, либо требует работы с матрицами (хотя я уверен что есть способ проще), либо объясняется людьми с космическим уровнем геометрических познаний. Хотелось бы увидеть просто код.

Comment: Из космоса для родственной задачи: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/933188/291659